# Understanding UIScrollView Constraints

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, autolayout

I have a `UIScrollView` with a `UIView` inside it and 3 `UITableViews` inside the view and I have the following constraints for the view :

[image]

In my code, exactly in `ViewDidLayoutSubviews` I have the following code

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [_containerScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(SCREEN_WIDTH * 3, [_containerScrollView frame].size.height)];

    [_contentViewWidthLayoutcontraint setConstant:SCREEN_WIDTH * 3];
    [[self view] layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

Which change the view width realtivly to the screen width.

My question is **why there is no conflict between the width constraint and the leading/trailing constraints ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your layout constraints, View's frame size is now become ScrollView's contentSize.
So if you change _contentViewWidthLayoutcontraint's constant, it is same as you change ScrollView contentSize.width.

Note that ScrollView.frame.size and ScrollView.contentSize are totally different.

Comment: so you mean I can remove the first line in my code?, also I have a problem with width and leading/trailing constraints. Aren't they conflicted ?!

Comment: Yes, you can remove first line.

Comment: Width and lead/trailing may have conflict in some cases, like UIView.